# Twilio SMS notification for Two Factor Authentication in ASP.NET Core 7.0 is not working

Tags: asp.net-core, twilio

I am trying to establish SMS notification for two factor authentication in an ASP.NET Core 7.0 project. I have created a trial account on Twilio. When I log in using my email and password, the code for the SMS is kicked in. However, I am getting the following error:

> ApiException: The 'To' number 512####### is not a valid phone number.

In the above message, I have changed some of the numbers in the phone number into "#". I tried different formats of the phone number, some of which are shown below. However, all of them displayed the same error.

```
+1 512 ### ####
1512#######
(512) ### ####
```

This is my code:

```
if (provider.Any(p => p == "Phone"))
{
    var token = await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, "Phone");
    await _smsSenderService.SendSMSAsync(user.PhoneNumber, $"OTP:{token}");
}
else if (provider.Any(e => e == "Email"))
{
    var token = await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, "Email");
    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(user.Email, "Email 2FA Code", $"<h1>{token}</h1>");
}

public async Task SendSMSAsync(string toPhone, string message)
    {
        TwilioClient.Init(_twilioSettings.AccountSID, 
              _twilioSettings.AuthToken);
        await MessageResource.CreateAsync(
            to: toPhone,
            from: _twilioSettings.FromPhone,
            body: message
        );
    }
```

Based upon my Google search I changed the version of the Twilio NuGet package from 8.02 to 6.11 and still the same error persists.

Comment: Could you post the `SendSMSAsync` method as well?

Comment: Hi benjs, I have included the SendSMSAsync method.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. `to: new PhoneNumber(toPhone)` should fix your problem.

Comment: Hi benjs, I tried your solution, still didn't receive any text message. I tried with and without +1 in front of the phone number.